# Money Regex, Optional dollar sign

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to get the dollar sign to be optional to validate a dollar amount.

current expression:

```
public static function isValidDollars($amount)
{
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]*(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/", $amount){return true;}
else {return false;}
}
```

If I add "\$\?" to the beginning it doesn't work.  I know the dollar sign has to be escaped, I'm not sure what I'm missing because this should pretty simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure to use single quote
2. Escape the dollar character `$`
3. make it optional

Your regex:

```
'/^\$?[0-9]*(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/'
```

Comment: The type of quote doesn't matter in this case actually as the `$` is escaped anyway.

Comment: I guess main problem was escaping `?` in OP's regex.

Comment: I'm starting to feel silly, the recommendation of adding "\$?" to the beginning is still making my function return false when there is a $ sign in the amount.

Comment: Nevermind, the problem was that I wasn't using single quotes, sorry about that.  I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. @AmalMurali Note use of single quote case here.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It will require [double escaping](https://eval.in/143433). (PS. Creating a demo from mobile can be painful :p)

Comment: @anubhava : i think the decimal point needs it own optional quantifier, since a number (of any base) ending with the radix point but no digits to its right is still valid representation.

Comment: Yes agree in theory